# Draw elliptical arc between 2 points using bezier curve

Tags: matlab, math, svg

I need a bezier curve to join the end points of 2 arbitrary lines smoothly. The lines are all either perpendicular or parallel. By "smoothly" I mean I want the curve's tangent at the end points to have the same slope as the lines.

I'm going to be using MatLab (Octave actually) to write the xml for an svg. So I need a formula to output the positions of the bezier curve's control points based on the positions of the endpoints.

Any help?

Comment: [SVG supports elliptical arcs.](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) I hope you have an amazing reason for deciding to use a bezier curve.

Comment: I also need to be able to draw S-Curves, but I'd like to have one formula that calculate control point locations for both the arcs and S-curves

Comment: @m7913d I haven't tried anything so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If lines are parallel but shifted, then you cannot draw single arc to connect them smoothly, so cubic Bezier curve (that can have S-form) is more suitable.

Let we have the first endpoint P0 with unit direction vector T0, and second endpoint P3 with unit direction vector T3. Control points of cubic Bezier lie on lines continuations. To make curve smooth, we should choose distance of conttrol points from endpoints. Empirical value is about half of distance between endpoints. Method works also for perpendicular lines.

```
 Dist = Sqrt((P0.X - P3.X)^2 + (P0.Y - P3.Y)^2)
 Control1.X = P0.X + T0.X *  Dist / 2
 Control1.Y = P0.Y + T0.Y *  Dist / 2
 Control2.X = P3.X - T3.X *  Dist / 2    //account for T3 direction here
 Control2.Y = P3.Y - T3.Y *  Dist / 2
```

Example of curve generated with described approach:

[image]

Comment: I'm wary of just using half the distance between the ends, otherwise, I would have done that in the first place

Comment: It is just my empirical value that provides rather smooth connection in the most of my test cases. Is it inappropriate for your use cases?

Comment: I'm not sure but I used Solidworks to manually make this curve before using its spline tool and I'm supposed to replicate that

Comment: But you have not explained in question what curve you need. Wanted "smooth" - I gave  smooth. Works for S-curve and arc. And how does Solidworks curve look?

Comment: I'm not sure what curve I need but I did want it to closely match an elliptical arc and I was planning on using the same parameters to form S-curves

Comment: Note that control points of Bezier for circular arc approximation (1/4 of circle) lie at distance 0.557*radius, so 0.5 distance coefficient here seems rather consistent

Comment: That's true. I came across that before but I was afraid that some end points' x and y differences wouldn't be equal and couldn't lie on a quarter circle

Comment: It is not a problem. Imagine that your lines are axis-aligned - you can use X-difference for control point at continuation of horizontal line, and Y-difference for control point at continuation of vertical line.